# Wordpress: page linking in single page project

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am trying to build a small single page wordpress theme, but struggling to find a way to make the navigation menu work.

The pages are loaded with this function: http://pastebin.com/Di5MhS8y . Each page is displayed as a section of my homepage, based on its menu_order.

If i make a custom menu voice linking outsite my website (tried with www.google.com) the menu works just fine.
Problems arise when i try to link to a single section of my website. The whole page gets reloaded and i'm brought back at the top of it.

I reckon i should maybe give a specific id to each section, and link to it, but i'm not sure. Any suggestion would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to give each section an ID.
if you want clean URLS you can create a function with Jquery

here's one i used in a one page [website](http://prospectcommons.com/)

```
var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
      var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body', 'document', 'window');
      //console.log(scrollElem);

      $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
        var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
        if (  locationPath == thisPath
        && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
        && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
          var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
          if (target) {
            //console.log('Target: ' + target + ' offset: ' + targetOffset);
            $(this).click(function(event) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
              event.preventDefault();
              $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000, function() {
              //console.log($(scrollElem).scrollTop());
                location.hash = target;
                $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 0);
              });
            });
          }
        }
      });

      // use the first element that is "scrollable"
      function scrollableElement(els) {
        for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
          var el = arguments[i],
              $scrollElement = $(el);
          if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
            return el;
          } else {
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
            var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
            //console.log(el + ': ' + $scrollElement.scrollTop());
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
            if (isScrollable) {
              return el;
            }
          }
        }
        return 'body';
      }
```